# Open ViewController from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I'm sending push notification to app which is terminated and it seems that only this method is triggered. I want to open ViewController when app is launched with push notification, but it doesn't do anything just opens app.

I tried to achieve that with this code:

```
if (launchOptions != nil) {

            NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
            NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
            if (apsInfo)
            {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"openNews" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
            }


}
```

and tried this as well ..

```
if (launchOptions != nil) {

            NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
            if (userInfo != nil)
            {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"openNews" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
            }
}
```

Any ideas how to launch ViewController when app is terminated with push notification?

So I have tried to save notification info to NSUserDefaults if launchOptions != nil just to check if Im receiving notification info and that part of code is triggered and it is but for some reason this part is not working:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"openNews" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

but Im using same method and everywhere and it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work because you are posting a notification with no one to catch it yet.

Hmm, what you can do here is to set the initial ViewController of your application when it receives the launchOptions you specified.

You can set it using this:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourStoryboardId"];

self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Be careful though in designing your navigations. Especially if you want your initial ViewController to be a page with back button that access the navigation stack.

Since you will make it your initial view controller, if it tries to popViewController, it will **pop** to nothing.

EDIT:

If you want it to be opened from the MainVC with a delay, you can put tnis in your MainVC

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(openAnotherVC:)
name:@"YourPostNotificationName" object:nil];
```

Then navigate to your desired VC in **openAnotherVC:** method

Comment: can I just post notification to open ViewController with delay? for example 1s delay?

Comment: hmm yeah, you can put the handler of your postNotification on your MainViewController and open the VC from there.

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if it still doesn't work